# Replace a series of substrings by one copy

Tags: java, regex

For a given word, I want to search for all the substrings that appear next to each other at least 3 times, and replace all of them by only one. I know how to do this when the substring is only one character. For instance, the code below returns "Bah" for the input string "Bahhhhhhh":

```
String term = "Bahhhhhhh";
term = term.replaceAll("(.)\\1{2,}", "$1");
```

However, I need a more generic pattern that converts "Bahahahaha" into "Baha".

Comment: This doesn't work for Bahahahahahaha. It becomes Bahaha

Comment: @mossaab, that's probably due to a greedy + operator. Try +?

Comment: @mossaab, It thinks "haha" is repeated three times.

Comment: @Alex, That's right. It was captured by Prince John Wesley.

Comment: @Peter, correct. But also "ha" is repeated 6 times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    String[] terms = { "Bahhhhhhh", "Bahahahaha" };
    for (String term : terms) {
        System.out.println(term.replaceAll("(.+?)\\1{2,}", "$1"));
    }
```

#### Output:

```
Bah 
Baha
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work for repetitions of 1, 2, or 3 characters long.

```
String term = "Bahhhhhhh";
term = term.replaceAll("(.{1,3})\\1{2,}", "$1");
```

You'll want to be careful to avoid **huge backtracking performance hits**.  That's why I limited it to 1-3 characters.

Comment: This does the job for the limited constraint. But I prefer (.+?)

Comment: @mossaab, I hope you don't plan to process whole documents with `(.+?)`, because I don't think that it will perform well.  A word at a time should be fine.

Comment: This is for a Lucene analyzer. So the documents are already tokenized. So, yes, I'm working at the word level.

Comment: I love lucene!  Best of luck!